# Set Hindi as locale in VSCode

Tags: localization, visual-studio-code, hindi

I'm unable to set hindi as a locale in VSCode.
I know that it is added in the list of community driven languages as suggested in 
https://github.com/Microsoft/Localization/wiki/Visual-Studio-Code-Community-Localization-Project

However, I can't understand how to include and use it in VSCode.
Kindly help with the steps required to add the same. 
Btw, there is no hindi language pack available in the marketplace,is there some other way to get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as it stands there is no other way to get it other than marketplace unless the following is published as stated [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Localization/wiki/How-to-request-a-new-UI-language-for-VS-Code-project) on point no. 5:

> After translation coverage reach 50% and below files are fully localized, we will publish language pack of this language in Marketplace. We encourage community members to publish language pack by yourself.